# Creating different dataframe sizes when grouping in dplyr and summerising with summerise_by_time

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, grouping

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> head(subppm)
  File        ChunkEnd       DPM Nall MinsOn area station deployment cpod
1 File1.CP3 11/4/2014 00:00   0  287      1   FB     FB1      FB1Ha  917
2 File2.CP3 11/4/2014 00:01   0   48      1   FB     FB1      FB1Ha  917
3 File3.CP3 11/4/2014 00:02   0   57      1   FB     FB1      FB1Ha  917
4 File4.CP3 11/4/2014 00:03   0   44      1   FB     FB1      FB1Ha  917
5 File5.CP3 11/4/2014 00:04   0   20      1   FB     FB1      FB1Ha  917
6 File6.CP3 11/4/2014 00:05   0    9      1   FB     FB1      FB1Ha  917
             DateTime
1 2014-04-11 00:00:00
2 2014-04-11 00:00:01
3 2014-04-11 00:00:02
4 2014-04-11 00:00:03
5 2014-04-11 00:00:04
6 2014-04-11 00:00:05

> sapply(subppm,class)
$File
[1] "character"

$ChunkEnd
[1] "character"

$DPM
[1] "integer"

$Nall
[1] "integer"

$MinsOn
[1] "integer"

$area
[1] "character"

$station
[1] "character"

$deployment
[1] "character"

$cpod
[1] "character"

$DateTime
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I am attempting to group these variables by the $area variable, and sum the $DPM variable by month according to $DateTime. DPM is a 0/1, so summing all the 1s will give me an idea of how many minutes had data a month. To do this I am using dplyr and timetk.

```
histData=subppm %>%
  group_by(area)+
  summarise_by_time(.data = subppm,
                    .date_var = DateTime,
                    .by ='month',
                    value = sum(DPM, na.rm = TRUE)
  )

Error in Ops.data.frame(subppm %>% group_by(area), summarise_by_time(.data = subppm,  : 
  ‘+’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

That produces the above error. The thing is, I can't see a way to create dataframes that are the same size. I am using the area to group, but we collected data at different areas at different times. I've tried removing the nas, but that doesn't help the issue. I also can't seem to find a way to solve this issue that takes the two groupings, area and time, into consideration.

According to [this](https://business-science.github.io/timetk/reference/summarise_by_time.html) example, this method should work. The output format in this example is exactly what I am looking for.

Thoughts?

Reproducible data:

```
dates1=seq(from = as.Date('2019-01-01 00:00'), to = as.Date('2019-07-10 00:00'), by = 1)
dates2=seq(from = as.Date('2019-05-01 00:00'), to = as.Date('2019-10-10 00:00'), by = 1)
dates3=seq(from = as.Date('2019-03-01 00:00'), to = as.Date('2019-07-31 00:00'), by = 1) 


data1=data.frame(area='group1', dates=dates1)
data2=data.frame(area='group2', dates=dates2)
data3=data.frame(area='group3', dates=dates3)

data1$DPM=rbinom(n=nrow(data1), size=1, prob=0.05)
data2$DPM=rbinom(n=nrow(data2), size=1, prob=0.05)
data3$DPM=rbinom(n=nrow(data3), size=1, prob=0.05)

data=rbind(data1,data2,data3)
```

Comment: Reproducible dataset example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `+` at the end of the second line where there should be a dplyr pipe `%>%`. That produces the given error.

Comment: Man, got my lingo crossed. I'm using ggplot in the same script. Thanks for the obvious spot!